# How can the electronic partition function be dependend on temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

If we just look at the first two terms of the electronic partition function:

$$q_{elec}(T) = g_1 + g_2 \times e^{\frac{-ε}{k_B \times T}} + ...$$

And remember that temperature is a measurement of mean kinetic energy of a system (translational, vibrational, rotational), why is T used in the electronic component?

Imagine I pump energy into my cup of coffee, which cause it to rise in temperature and therefore populates more and more energy states (Q rises) until the mean kinetic energy reaches such a high level, that the electronic energy gap can be bridged to the first excited state so $q_{elec}$ starts to contribute to available energy states more and more, but simultaneously that contribution doesn't show up in the temperature of the system, because it's stored in the electronic energy...

Electronic energy gaps are the farthest apart but coming closer together with higher states, rotational & translational are spaced more closely but going farther apart with higher energy states. So imagine molecules which total energy is the sum of all individual:

$$ε = ε_{trans} + ε_{rot} + ε_{elec}$$

(I've consciously omitted vibration, because vibration with higher states, the energy differences become smaller).

If we now reach the theoretical temperature turning point, in which the electronic energy states are closer together than the vibrational and rotational, we couldn't tell the contribution from $q_{elec}$ anymore, because temperature doesn't change, although we put more energy in the system, which is stored in electronic energy and doesn't account for temperature. So we could measure the temperature but couldn't tell for sure how much $q_{elec}$ contributes...

Comment: In this  there is an explanation given certain conditions  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Statistical_Thermodynamics_(Jeschke)/06%3A_Partition_Functions_of_Gases/6.06%3A_Electronic_Partition_Function  .